# Is blood typing still useful for analysis of ancient tissues?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, dna-sequencing, hematology

**Modern techniques.**

In recent years, DNA sequencing has become extremely cheap. This, compounded by the ability to PCR miniscule samples to viable samples for analysis, means that aDNA can be extracted and analysed from ancient tissue samples that 20 years ago would have been impossible to sequence.

**Pre-sequencing techniques.**

However biochemical analysis of ancient tissues preceded the human genome project, which revolutionised sequencing technology.

Although blood typing was fiddly, grossly time consuming, and expensive, people were able to define historical lineages.

**Question**

How does the "old-school" approach of blood-typing compare in terms of cost, accuracy, sample required, and speed against the modern aDNA analysis? Do those sort of experiments still have a place in a modern ancient tissue lab?